# Sturm-Liouville operator completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Can someone please provide a reference to a proof of the completeness of the eigenvectors of a Sturm-Liouville operator, it would also be great if the aforementioned proof relies on operator theory and functional analysis. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The completeness of the eigenvectors of a Sturm-Lioiville operator follows immediately from the spectral theorem for compact operators.

A Sturm-Liouville operator always (when zero is not an eigenvalue, which can always be arranged) has a right inverse, the Green's function operator (also called the solution operator). This Green's function operator is a compact and self-adjoint operator.

If you want to see the concrete definition of the Green's function operator (and the proof that it is a right-inverse), you can check "Linear Functional Analysis" by Rynne and Youngson, Section $8.4$ in the $2$nd edition.